# This is throwing error in assignment line("list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"). Could you plz tell me why?

Tags: python-3.x, list

a = list(map(int,input("Enter the list: ").split()))
first, middle, last = a[0], a[1, -1], a[-1]
print(first, middle, last)

Comment: What is `a[1, -1]` supposed to be? You can't index a list with a tuple. Did you mean `a[1:-1]`?

Comment: Any question regarding an error should include the full error you receive along with your expected result.

Comment: @chepner Yes that's what I intended. I see it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can try;

```
first, middle, last = a[0], a[1:-1], a[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see it now.

Comment: or more simply `first, middle, last = a` (assuming a has three elements)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```py
a = list(map(int,input("Enter the list: ").split()))
first, middle, last = a[0], a[1:-1], a[-1]
print(first, middle, last)
```

What you were getting wrong before was that you had `a[1,-1]` instead of `a[1:-1]`.  To do a range of numbers, you can do `a[start:end]`.  Also, you have to input the list of numbers separated by spaces, otherwise it will not work.  If you want to input something separated by commas or different characters, simply change what's inside the `.split()`.  For the middle variable, you will get a list of numbers because it is a range of numbers.  If you do not want to get a list as the middle numbers, you can do:

```py
a = list(map(str,input("Enter the list: ").split()))
print(' '.join(a))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I oversaw the error and couldn't understand the error. I am just starting in python.

Comment: That's alright!  I was like this when I started out with python as well.